# Pandas read_html: Entire table from partially displayed table

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I wanted to get the entire table from this website: https://www.nba.com/players (either as csv or pd.DataFrame). So I tried to run (Python 3.9)

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://www.nba.com/players')
```

but I only got a partial table, namely the 50 rows displayed by default when opening the website. To instead view the *entire table* on the website one can select "Show Historic" and "Rows • Page All" at the top of the table. But this does not change the URL (hence I cannot use `pd.read_html(<URL>)`).

**Question**: How do I modify the command above to import the *entire table*?

(Also open to 'non-pandas' alternatives)

Answer (score 1):

The data available from an api on the site.
this code should get you the data:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Origin': 'https://www.nba.com',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.7,no;q=0.6',
}

params = (
    ('College', ''),
    ('Country', ''),
    ('DraftPick', ''),
    ('DraftRound', ''),
    ('DraftYear', ''),
    ('Height', ''),
    ('Historical', '1'),
    ('LeagueID', '00'),
    ('Season', '2020-21'),
    ('SeasonType', 'Regular^%^20Season'),
    ('TeamID', '0'),
    ('Weight', ''),
)

response = requests.get('https://stats.nba.com/stats/playerindex', headers=headers, params=params)

playerData = response.json()["resultSets"][0]["rowSet"]
headers = response.json()["resultSets"][0]["headers"]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(playerData,columns=headers)
```